# In excel how to use a formula to change sub row based off header rows

Tags: excel-formula

Example: [image: Example of what I would like to accomplish with formula]

I have files that do not have set number of records. I will have an "M" record that contains the values I want shared with all "C" records that belong to the "M" record. I am not sure how to do this, was playing around with index, match, & max but could not figure out how to accomplish this.

Comment: Sorry I am new to posting questions to stack overflow but thought the image would show up in post not be a link.

Comment: I don't think it's obvious from what you have here what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: @C.Schultz regarding the image, what you did is just fine.  Without enough rep you aren't allowed to insert the image for display.  Once you earn enough rep you will be able to do it

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand of what you asked, try this:

in `B2`:

```
=IF($A1="M";B1;VLOOKUP($A2;$A$1:$B$22;2;FALSE))
```

in `C2`:

```
=IF($A1="M";C1;VLOOKUP($A2;$A$1:$C$22;3;FALSE))
```

then copy the formulas to the other rows with value "C" in the first column, respectively